# Product Attribute Shipping Fee - Catalog Input Type for store owner - price

Tags: product-attribute, shipping, shipping-charges

Admin has made
Product Attribute - Shipping Fee
Attribute Property
Catalog Input Type for Store Owner - Price

This product attribute will be shown at the time of product adding to admin or vendor in admin dashboard or vendor dashboard panel.

If admin or vendor write Shipping Fee = Rs 8 or $ 8 at the time of product adding

will this Shipping Fee amount will be added as shipping fee in the shopping cart with product price when customer add this product to cart ?

Screenshot 1 - http://prnt.sc/uaxh4b

[image]

Comment: anyone can comment on above question

Comment: can anyone answer